# Resolving trim() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in divi functions file

Tags: php, wordpress, divi

In a wordpress site made with divi, in the `functions.php` file in the divi theme includes builder folder, I'm getting an intermittent error on the line:

`$value        = substr( $value, 1, $value_length ) . trim();`

The error says `Warning: trim() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given`

Is this because there's nothing inside trim? But chaining it like this on the end it should refer to what it's chained onto, is that correct? So the `substr` of `$value`. Does this mean that `$value` is just not given? Or that when you get the `substr` there's nothing else there?

Would love to use javascript's console.log to see what's actually there round about now :D . Is there a php equivalent? Or some kind of plugin for php for dev tools where I can see the variables at any given moment?

Anyone know what the issue is here? I'm not even sure what this piece of code does at the moment, something to do with setting a css px value on some text I'm guessing..., and removing the `!important` property?

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_pb_get_value_unit' ) ) :
    /**
     * Get unit of given value
     *
     * @param string $value string with unit.
     * @param string $default_unit default unit.
     *
     * @return string unit name
     */
    function et_pb_get_value_unit( $value, $default_unit = 'px' ) {
        $value                   = isset( $value ) ? $value : '';
        $valid_one_char_units    = array( '%', 'x' );
        $valid_two_chars_units   = array( 'em', 'px', 'cm', 'mm', 'in', 'pt', 'pc', 'ex', 'vh', 'vw', 'ms' );
        $valid_three_chars_units = array( 'deg', 'rem' );
        $important               = '!important';
        $important_length        = strlen( $important );
        $value_length            = strlen( $value );

        if ( '' === $value || is_numeric( $value ) ) {
            return $default_unit;
        }

        if ( substr( $value, ( 0 - $important_length ), $important_length ) === $important ) {
            $value_length = $value_length - $important_length;
            $value        = substr( $value, 1, $value_length ) . trim();
        }

        if ( in_array( substr( $value, -3, 3 ), $valid_three_chars_units, true ) ) {
            return substr( $value, -3, 3 );
        }

        if ( in_array( substr( $value, -2, 2 ), $valid_two_chars_units, true ) ) {
            return substr( $value, -2, 2 );
        }

        if ( in_array( substr( $value, -1, 1 ), $valid_one_char_units, true ) ) {
            return substr( $value, -1, 1 );
        }

        return $default_unit;
    }
endif;
```

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory! Change it to `$value = trim(substr( $value, 1, $value_length ));`. You're working with `php` not `javascript`!

Comment: @Ruvee Thanks, I figured this was the probable issue. From what I can tell this is an error in the professional wordpress theme builder `divi` so it's kind of shocking to me that 1)the error exists, and 2) when I google the error nothing comes up. You'd think this issue would have been written about on the internets before.

Comment: No problem! Well, not sure, i haven't used `divi` or any other theme builders. I write my own themes but the error was exactly telling you what's happening. Not sure why theme developers have written the syntax like that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining like that is a feature of other languages (like JavaScript), however it  is **not** a feature of PHP. As it's written, you're "concatenating a 'trimmed `null`'" onto the end of the value, which, doesn't really make sense.

Take a look at the [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function documentation - the `string` argument is required so it knows what to trim.

If you wanted to "chain" like that, you'd actually need to encompass the value with the `trim` like so:

```
$value = trim( substr( $value, 1, $value_length ) );
```

You may see "chained" functions like that referred to as "nested" as far as PHP is concerned.

As far as what the code is doing, it's a relatively convoluted way of returning the unit type from a value - probably to see if it's `rem`, `px`, `%` - etc for use in other calculations elsewhere. It could be simplified quite a bit ( perhaps a single line with regex), but that's beyond the scope of this question

Comment: Summary: don't do `$stringValue.trim()`, do `trim($stringValue)`.